# Why can't I upload a portfolio to Yahoo Finance?

Tags: upload, yahoo

I used to be able to upload a new portfolio to Yahoo Finance by, while logged in, going to

- https://finance.yahoo.com/portfolios

clicking "Import", and submitting a CSV file. But when I do that now, I get the error message:

> There was some error while importing your portfolio. Please Try Again.

I never found any documentation of the structure of CSV file it requires, but the structure that I found worked in the past was:

```
Symbol,Trade Date,Quantity,Purchase Price,Commission
AAPL,2024 02 04,100,200,0
MSFT,2024 02 04,100,400,0
GOOG,2024 02 04,100,150,0
```

I submitted a test file with those contents and the filename "yahootest.csv" and got the above error message.

I signed up for a subscription to Yahoo Support for about $5 a month and submitted this issue. I got a series of responses that were completely useless, and I cancelled the subscription.

I can't be the only person who is experiencing this new inability to upload a portfolio. I'm surprised that searching neither Google nor Stack Exchange brings up anything useful about that error message.

Has uploading portfolios been disabled, or am I doing something wrong?

It would be great if some other people would try uploading that file and see if you get the same error. Or better yet if you find a way to upload those data successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

**Trade Date Data Format**
`yyyymmdd` *not* `yyyy mm dd`

## Date Formatting Issue

The issue is with your date format. I performed a few tests and to the best of my knowledge based on those quick tests:

1. Only a **number** or an **empty value** can be used in the `Trade Date` field or you will trigger an error.
2. Any number can be used without triggering the error regardless of whether Yahoo Finance can interpret it as a valid date. In cases where it cannot, the value will be ignored.
3. Any value interpreted as a text string, such as `bob`, `2024 01 28`, or `1/28/2024`, will trigger an error.
4. Yahoo Finance accepts valid dates formatted as `yyyymmdd` such as `20240128`

> *I never found any documentation of the structure of CSV file it requires,*

I too was unable to find documentation and the information I found posted by other users regarding acceptable date formats was either incorrect or no longer relevant. In the end I ran some tests and also manually populated a portfolio in order to review the CSV format exported by Yahoo Finance in a text editor.

Comment: Well, isn't this interesting. Yahoo Support, even with a paid subscription (albeit very low cost), had no idea of this issue, but you figured it out. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: For some more information, my records show that I was entering the dates in format "yyyy mm dd" as late as Jan. 2023 without error. Then this error occurred the next time I tries to upload in May 2023. So Yahoo changed that format requirement somewhere between Jan. and May 2023. And apparently, even their support staff are not aware of that change, or of the current format requirement. I sent them the test file and they were clueless about the problem.

Comment: And more information: I did download a current portfolio to see if it would tell me anything about the problem. The downloads have two date fields, "Date" and "Trade Date". Field "Date" is the download date in format "yyyy mm dd". Field "Trade Date" is empty for trades previously uploaded. If a trade was entered manually, this field has a value for this in format "yyyymmdd". Since I rarely enter trades manually, when I did a download to check the data formats, the field "Trade Date" was all empty, so I got no clue of the date formatting problem, especially since "Date" was in "yyyy mm dd".

Comment: Correction: In downloads of portfolios uploaded previously, the field "Trade Date" is empty. But when I downloaded a portfolio that I uploaded today, that field is properly populated, with format "yyyymmdd". So it looks like maybe Yahoo had something funky going on with that field, which they have, maybe, fixed.

Comment: I get it. Troubleshooting is a voodoo science.  My first test I pasted your data in Sheets and exported as a CSV. Sheets understood your dates but exported them as date values (eg. `45331` not  `2024 01 09`) which didn't trigger an error in Yahoo Finance (YF). Eureka! Nope  It wasn't until much later that I picked up on the fact that YF was simply ignoring that data which prompted additional tests, including manually setting the field in YF as you did. That's why I qualified my answer in the way I did, as there may be other success/failure paths that are hidden based on my choice of tests